# ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on PlayerGril(). Expected 3, got 0. in Adobe Animate CC

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

When I debug my program, an error appears. Here it is:

```
ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on PlayerGril(). Expected 3, got 0.
    at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
    at flash.display::Sprite()
    at flash.display::MovieClip()
    at MainGame()[E:\folder ni cj\DMTHESIS\dmgame\MainGame.as:52]
    at Main/game()[E:\folder ni cj\DMTHESIS\dmgame\Main.as:188]
    at Main/skip()[E:\folder ni cj\DMTHESIS\dmgame\Main.as:185]
```

Here are my codes:

Main.as:

```
package {

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.text.*;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;
    import flash.events.TouchEvent;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.display.SimpleButton;

    public class Main extends MovieClip {

        public var playergril: PlayerGril;
        private var stageRef:Stage;
        private var thisThing:Object;
        public var mainmenu: MainMenu = new MainMenu();
        public var maingame: MainGame;
        public var startopt: StartOpt = new StartOpt();
        public var learnopt: LearnOpt = new LearnOpt();
        public var newload: NewLoad = new NewLoad();
        public var propocon: PropoCon = new PropoCon();
        public var setcon: SetCon = new SetCon();
        public var relationcon: RelationCon = new RelationCon();
        public var scrollinstructwin: ScrollInstructWin = new ScrollInstructWin();
        public var scrollstorywin: ScrollStoryWin = new ScrollStoryWin();

        public function Main() {
            addChild(mainmenu);

            mainmenu.x = 350;
            mainmenu.y = 290;

            mainmenu.btnStart.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, start);
            mainmenu.btnInstruct.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, instruct);
            mainmenu.btnBye.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, bye);
        }
        public function start(event: MouseEvent): void {
            removeChild(mainmenu);
            addChild(startopt);

            startopt.x = 350;
            startopt.y = 290;

            startopt.btnLearn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, learn);
            startopt.btnPlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, laro);
            startopt.btnBack.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, back);
        }
        public function instruct(event: MouseEvent): void {
            removeChild(mainmenu);
            addChild(scrollinstructwin);

            scrollinstructwin.x = 36.20;
            scrollinstructwin.y = 21.50;
            var max_Y: Number = 0;
            var min_Y: Number = Math.min(0, stage.stageHeight - scrollinstructwin.scrollinstruct.height);
            var startY: Number;
            var startMouseY: Number;

            addChild(scrollinstructwin.scrollinstruct);

            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);

            function mouseDownHandler(event: MouseEvent): void {
                startY = scrollinstructwin.scrollinstruct.y;
                startMouseY = mouseY;

                stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, stagemouseMoveHandler, false, 0, true);
                stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stagemouseUpHandler, false, 0, true);
            }

            function stagemouseMoveHandler(event: MouseEvent): void {
                var offset_Y: Number = mouseY - startMouseY;
                scrollinstructwin.scrollinstruct.y = Math.max(Math.min(max_Y, startY + offset_Y), min_Y);
            }

            function stagemouseUpHandler(event: MouseEvent): void {
                stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, stagemouseMoveHandler);
                stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stagemouseUpHandler);
            }

            scrollinstructwin.btnGi.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gi);
        }
        public function bye(event: MouseEvent): void {
            NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit(0);
        }
        public function gi(event: MouseEvent): void {
            removeChild(scrollinstructwin);
            addChild(mainmenu);

            mainmenu.x = 350;
            mainmenu.y = 290;
        }
        public function back(event: MouseEvent): void {
            removeChild(startopt);
            addChild(mainmenu);

            mainmenu.x = 350;
            mainmenu.y = 290;
        }
        public function learn(event: MouseEvent): void {
            removeChild(startopt);
            addChild(learnopt);

            learnopt.x = 350;
            learnopt.y = 290;

            learnopt.btnPropo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, propo);
            learnopt.btnSets.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, sets);
            learnopt.btnRelations.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, relations);
            learnopt.btnBack3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, backo);
        }
        public function laro(event: MouseEvent): void {
            removeChild(startopt);
            addChild(newload);

            newload.x = 350;
            newload.y = 290;

            newload.btnNew.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, neww);
            newload.btnBack2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, backu);
        }
        public function backo(event: MouseEvent): void {
            removeChild(learnopt);
            addChild(startopt);

            startopt.x = 350;
            startopt.y = 290;
        }
        public function neww(event: MouseEvent): void {
            removeChild(newload);
            addChild(scrollstorywin);

            scrollstorywin.x = 51.15;
            scrollstorywin.y = 30.05;
            var maxY: Number = 0;
            var minY: Number = Math.min(0, stage.stageHeight - scrollstorywin.scrollcontent.height); 
            //var minY_: Number = Math.min(0, stage.stageHeight - scrollstorywin.scrollcontent2.height);
            var _startY: Number;
            var _startMouseY: Number;

            addChild(scrollstorywin.scrollcontent);

            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseoDownHandler);

            function mouseoDownHandler(event: MouseEvent): void {
                _startY = scrollstorywin.scrollcontent.y;
                _startMouseY = mouseY;

                /*_startY = scrollstorywin.scrollContent2.y;
                _startMouseY = mouseY;*/

                stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, stage_mouseMoveHandler, false, 0, true);
                stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stage_mouseUpHandler, false, 0, true);
            }

            function stage_mouseMoveHandler(event: MouseEvent): void {
                var offsetY: Number = mouseY - _startMouseY;
                scrollstorywin.scrollcontent.y = Math.max(Math.min(maxY, _startY + offsetY), minY);
                //scrollstorywin.scrollContent2.y = Math.max(Math.min(maxY, _startY + offsetY), minY_);
            }

            function stage_mouseUpHandler(event: MouseEvent): void {
                stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, stage_mouseMoveHandler);
                stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stage_mouseUpHandler);
            }

            scrollstorywin.btnCho.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nw);
            scrollstorywin.btnSkip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, skip);
            scrollstorywin.scrollcontent.btnCC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, cc);
            scrollstorywin.scrollcontent.btnAA.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, aa);
            //scrollstorywin.scrollcontent2.btnSaa.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, saa);
        }
        public function nw(event: MouseEvent): void {
            removeChild(scrollstorywin);
            addChild(newload);

            mainmenu.x = 350;
            mainmenu.y = 290;
        }
        private function skip(event: MouseEvent): void {
            removeChild(scrollstorywin);
            game();
        }
        private function game(){
            maingame = new MainGame(stageRef, thisThing);
            thisThing.visible = true;
            //addChild(maingame);

            maingame.x = 415.00;
            maingame.y = 228.00;
            maingame.gotoAndStop(1);
        }
        public function cc(event: MouseEvent): void {
            removeChild(scrollstorywin.scrollcontent);
            scrollstorywin.scrollcontent.gotoAndStop(2);
        }
        public function aa(event: MouseEvent): void {
            removeChild(scrollstorywin);
            addChild(newload);

            newload.x = 350;
            newload.y = 290;
        }
        /*public function saa(event: MouseEvent): void {
            removeChild(scrollstorywin.scrollcontent2);
            addChild(maingame);
        }*/
        public function backu(event: MouseEvent): void {
            removeChild(newload);
            addChild(startopt);

            startopt.x = 350;
            startopt.y = 290;
        }
        public function propo(event: MouseEvent): void {
            removeChild(learnopt);
            propocon.gotoAndStop(1);
            addChild(propocon);

            propocon.x = 414.80;
            propocon.y = 218.60;

            //propocon.btnBtm.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, popo);
            propocon.btnExit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, byeol);
            //propocon.btnQt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, qtu);
        }
        /*public function popo(event: MouseEvent): void {
            removeChild(propocon);
            addChild(learnopt);

            learnopt.x = 350;
            learnopt.y = 290;
        }*/
        public function byeol(event: MouseEvent): void {
            removeChild(propocon);
            addChild(learnopt);

            learnopt.x = 350;
            learnopt.y = 290;
        }
        /*public function qtu(event: MouseEvent): void {
            removeChild(propocon);
            addChild(mainmenu);

            mainmenu.x = 350;
            mainmenu.y = 290;
        }*/
        public function sets(event: MouseEvent): void {
            removeChild(learnopt);
            setcon.gotoAndStop(1);
            addChild(setcon);

            setcon.x = 412.45;
            setcon.y = 225.00;

            setcon.btnBai2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, byeo);
            //setcon.btnBtm2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pop);
            //setcon.btnQt2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, qti);
        }
        public function byeo(event: MouseEvent): void {
            removeChild(setcon);
            addChild(learnopt);

            learnopt.x = 350;
            learnopt.y = 290;
        }
        /*public function pop(event: MouseEvent): void {
            removeChild(setcon);
            addChild(learnopt);

            learnopt.x = 350;
            learnopt.y = 290;
        }
        public function qti(event: MouseEvent): void {
            removeChild(setcon);
            addChild(mainmenu);

            mainmenu.x = 350;
            mainmenu.y = 290;
        }*/
        public function relations(event: MouseEvent): void {
            removeChild(learnopt);
            relationcon.gotoAndStop(1);
            addChild(relationcon);

            relationcon.x = 400.00;
            relationcon.y = 225.00;

            relationcon.btnBai3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, byel);
            //relationcon.btnBtm3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, poup);
            //relationcon.btnQt3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, qtui);
        }
        public function byel(event: MouseEvent): void {
            removeChild(relationcon);
            addChild(learnopt);

            learnopt.x = 350;
            learnopt.y = 290;
        }
        /*public function poup(event: MouseEvent): void {
            removeChild(relationcon);
            addChild(learnopt);

            learnopt.x = 350;
            learnopt.y = 290;
        }
        public function qtui(event: MouseEvent): void {
            removeChild(relationcon);
            addChild(mainmenu);

            mainmenu.x = 350;
            mainmenu.y = 290;
        }*/
    }
}
```

Based on the error, here are the affected codes in this AS file:

Line 185: `game();`

Line 188: `maingame = new MainGame(stageRef, thisThing);`

MainGame.as (from movieclip symbol):

```
package {

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.text.*;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class MainGame extends MovieClip {

        private var main: Main;
        public var playergril: PlayerGril;
        public var key: Key = new Key();
        public var door: Door = new Door();
        public var pausewin: PauseWin = new PauseWin();
        public var corekwin: CorekWin = new CorekWin();
        public var maliwin: MaliWin = new MaliWin();
        public var gameoverwin: GameOverWin = new GameOverWin();
        public var scorerr: Scorer = new Scorer();
        public var timerr: Timerr = new Timerr();
        public var lives: Lives = new Lives();
        public var room: Room = new Room();
        public var room2: Room2 = new Room2();
        public var room3: Room3 = new Room3();
        public var room4: Room4 = new Room4();
        public var room5: Room5 = new Room5();
        public var quizquest: QuizQuest = new QuizQuest();
        public var quizquest2: QuizQuest2 = new QuizQuest2();
        public var quizquest3: QuizQuest3 = new QuizQuest3();
        public var quizquest4: QuizQuest4 = new QuizQuest4();
        public var quizquest5: QuizQuest5 = new QuizQuest5();
        public var gamestage: int = 0;
        public var buhay: int = 0;
        public var iskoru: int = 0;
        private var stageRef:Stage;
        private var thisThing:Object;
        private var walkRate:Number;
        private var targetBuffer:Number;
        /*public var v: Number = 5;
        public var dir: int = 0;
        public var clickPoint: Point = new Point();
        public var angle: Number;
        public var goX: Number;
        public var goY: Number;*/

        public function MainGame(stageRef:Stage, thisThing:Object) {
            this.stageRef = stageRef;
            this.thisThing = thisThing;
            this.scorerr.visible = false;
            this.timerr.visible = false;
            this.pausewin.visible = false;
            this.quizquest.visible = false;
            this.quizquest2.visible = false;
            this.quizquest3.visible = false;
            this.quizquest4.visible = false;
            this.quizquest5.visible = false;
            startgame();
        }
        private function startgame() {
            playergril = new PlayerGril(stageRef, walkRate, targetBuffer);
            for (var i = 0; i > 5; i++) {
                buhay = 3;
                this.lives.txtLives.text = buhay.toString();
                if (gamestage == 1) {
                    this.room.x = -15.00;
                    this.room.y = -1.00;
                    this.room.visible = true;
                    //walk();
                    addChild(key);
                    if (key.hitTestObject(playergril)) {
                        this.gotoAndStop(2);
                        i++;
                        quiztime();
                    }
                } else if (gamestage == 2) {
                    this.room2.x = -15.85;
                    this.room2.y = -0.90;
                    this.room2.visible = true;
                    //walk();
                    addChild(key);
                    if (key.hitTestObject(playergril)) {
                        this.gotoAndStop(4);
                        i++;
                        quiztime2();
                    }
                } else if (gamestage == 3) {
                    this.room3.x = -15.80;
                    this.room3.y = -1.00;
                    this.room3.visible = true;
                    //walk();
                    addChild(key);
                    if (key.hitTestObject(playergril)) {
                        this.gotoAndStop(6);
                        i++;
                        quiztime3();
                    }
                } else if (gamestage == 4) {
                    this.room4.x = -15.40;
                    this.room4.y = -2.05;
                    this.room4.visible = true;
                    //walk();
                    addChild(key);
                    if (key.hitTestObject(playergril)) {
                        this.gotoAndStop(8);
                        i++;
                        quiztime4();
                    }
                } else if (gamestage == 5) {
                    this.room5.x = -15.80;
                    this.room5.y = -0.95;
                    this.room5.visible = true;
                    //walk();
                    addChild(key);
                    if (key.hitTestObject(playergril)) {
                        this.gotoAndStop(10);
                        i++;
                        quiztime5();
                    }
                }

                this.btnPause.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, oop);
            }
            function oop(event: MouseEvent): void {
                stage.frameRate = 0;
                this.gotoAndStop(11);

                this.pausewin.btnResume.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, op);
            }
            function op(event: MouseEvent): void {
                stage.frameRate = 24;
            }
        }
        /*public function walk() {
            this.btnForward.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myClickReaction);
            function myClickReaction(e: MouseEvent): void {
                var target = e.target;

                if (target == this.btnForward) {

                    goX = mouseX;
                    goY = mouseY;
                }
                addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
            }
        }
        function onEnterFrame(event: Event): void {
            var xDistance: Number = clickPoint.x - playergril.x;
            var yDistance: Number = clickPoint.y - playergril.y;
            var angle: Number = Math.atan2(yDistance, xDistance);
            playergril.x += v * Math.cos(angle);
            playergril.y += v * Math.sin(angle);
            playergril.gotoAndPlay(1);
            if (xDistance <= 0) {
                trace("works");
                playergril.gotoAndPlay(8);
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
            }
        }*/
        public function quiztime() {
            this.quizquest.visible = true;
            this.scorerr.visible = true;
            this.timerr.visible = true;
            this.quizquest.ans11.buttonMode = true;
            this.quizquest.ans12.buttonMode = true;
            this.quizquest.ans13.buttonMode = true;

            this.quizquest.ans11.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttones1);
            this.quizquest.ans12.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttones2);
            this.quizquest.ans13.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttones3);

            function buttones1(eventObject: MouseEvent): void {
                this.gotoAndStop(12);
                iskoru += 1;
                this.scorerr.txtSkor.text = iskoru.toString();
            }
            function buttones2(eventObject: MouseEvent): void {
                this.gotoAndStop(13);
                buhay -= 1;
                this.lives.txtLives.text = buhay.toString();
            }

            function buttones3(eventObject: MouseEvent): void {
                this.gotoAndStop(13);
                buhay -= 1;
                this.lives.txtLives.text = buhay.toString();
            }
        }

        public function quiztime2() {
            this.quizquest2.visible = true;
            this.scorerr.visible = true;
            this.timerr.visible = true;
            this.quizquest2.ans21.buttonMode = true;
            this.quizquest2.ans22.buttonMode = true;
            this.quizquest2.ans23.buttonMode = true;

            this.quizquest2.ans21.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttones4);
            this.quizquest2.ans22.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttones5);
            this.quizquest2.ans23.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttones6);
            function buttones4(eventObject: MouseEvent): void {
                this.gotoAndStop(13);
                buhay -= 1;
                this.lives.txtLives.text = buhay.toString();
            }
            function buttones5(eventObject: MouseEvent): void {
                this.gotoAndStop(13);
                buhay -= 1;
                this.lives.txtLives.text = buhay.toString();
            }
            function buttones6(eventObject: MouseEvent): void {
                this.gotoAndStop(12);
                iskoru += 1;
                this.scorerr.txtSkor.text = iskoru.toString();
            }
        }

        public function quiztime3() {
            this.quizquest3.visible = true;
            this.scorerr.visible = true;
            this.timerr.visible = true;
            this.quizquest3.ans31.buttonMode = true;
            this.quizquest3.ans32.buttonMode = true;
            this.quizquest3.ans33.buttonMode = true;

            this.quizquest3.ans31.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttones7);
            this.quizquest3.ans32.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttones8);
            this.quizquest3.ans33.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttones9);
            function buttones7(eventObject: MouseEvent): void {
                this.gotoAndStop(13);
                buhay -= 1;
                this.lives.txtLives.text = buhay.toString();
            }
            function buttones8(eventObject: MouseEvent): void {
                this.gotoAndStop(13);
                buhay -= 1;
                this.lives.txtLives.text = buhay.toString();
            }
            function buttones9(eventObject: MouseEvent): void {
                this.gotoAndStop(12);
                iskoru += 1;
                this.scorerr.txtSkor.text = iskoru.toString();
            }
        }

        public function quiztime4() {
            this.quizquest4.visible = true;
            this.scorerr.visible = true;
            this.timerr.visible = true;
            this.quizquest4.ans41.buttonMode = true;
            this.quizquest4.ans42.buttonMode = true;
            this.quizquest4.ans43.buttonMode = true;

            this.quizquest4.ans41.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttones10);
            this.quizquest4.ans42.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttones11);
            this.quizquest4.ans43.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttones12);
            function buttones10(eventObject: MouseEvent): void {
                this.gotoAndStop(13);
                buhay -= 1;
                lives.txtLives.text = buhay.toString();
            }
            function buttones11(eventObject: MouseEvent): void {
                this.gotoAndStop(13);
                buhay -= 1;
                this.lives.txtLives.text = buhay.toString();
            }
            function buttones12(eventObject: MouseEvent): void {
                this.gotoAndStop(12);
                iskoru += 1;
                this.scorerr.txtSkor.text = iskoru.toString();
            }
        }

        public function quiztime5() {
            this.quizquest5.visible = true;
            this.scorerr.visible = true;
            this.timerr.visible = true;
            this.quizquest5.ans51.buttonMode = true;
            this.quizquest5.ans52.buttonMode = true;
            this.quizquest5.ans53.buttonMode = true;

            this.quizquest5.ans51.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttones13);
            this.quizquest5.ans52.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttones14);
            this.quizquest5.ans53.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttones15);
            function buttones13(eventObject: MouseEvent): void {
                this.gotoAndStop(12);
                iskoru += 1;
                this.scorerr.txtSkor.text = iskoru.toString();
            }
            function buttones14(eventObject: MouseEvent): void {
                this.gotoAndStop(13);
                buhay -= 1;
                this.lives.txtLives.text = buhay.toString();
            }
            function buttones15(eventObject: MouseEvent): void {
                this.gotoAndStop(13);
                buhay -= 1;
                this.lives.txtLives.text = buhay.toString();
            }
            if (buhay == 0) {
                this.gotoAndStop(14);
                this.gameoverwin.btnTry.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dasi);
            }
            function dasi(event: MouseEvent): void {
                this.gameoverwin.visible = false;
                startgame();
                this.btnPause.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tgil);
            }
            function tgil(event: MouseEvent): void {
                this.gotoAndStop(11);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And its affected code from line 52: `public function MainGame(stageRef:Stage, thisThing:Object) {`

I can't find the wrong code line from it. I'm trying to fix the errors but still, that error appears. Is there any problem on my code? How can I fix those errors? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()"... where is this code? constructChildren()?  Please post that.  This should be where the error is

Comment: the addChild() and removeChild() right?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I fix those errors? Any help would be appreciated

Use `trace` to double check any variables that may be causing issues.

For example in your **MainGame.as** and regarding that `private function startgame()`, before you declare that `= new PlayerGril` code, why not check if the input parameters are **actually valid**?

```
trace("check stageRef     : " + stageRef);     //if null = wont work
trace("check walkRate     : " + walkRate);     //if NaN = wont work
trace("check targetBuffer : " + targetBuffer); //if NaN = wont work

playergril = new PlayerGril(stageRef, walkRate, targetBuffer); //are all 3 parameters ok?
```

Notice as well that in making `public class MainGame` you did create variables like `stageRef`, `walkRate` and `targetBuffer` which is good, but you **never gave a value to those variables**.

We have the idea that `walkRate` is a number but **nowhere** in any code running **before** calling `function startgame()` do you ever tell the compiler exactly **how much** is `walkRate`!!

You think : `playergril = new PlayerGril(stageRef, walkRate, targetBuffer);`

Compiler sees : `playergril = new PlayerGril(nothing, nothing, nothing);`